# Return content from before block in Sinatra if json is not being sent

Tags: backbone.js, sinatra

I was wondering how to return content from the `before` block if the request is not being sent with json. This would be valuable for compatibility with `backbone` where much of the rest of the file is RESTful and only one version of content is being sent otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [`halt`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting)?

```
before '/' do
  halt "Early return" if some_condition
end
```